# Log in with different custom link but Salesforce only recognize as 1

Tags: salesforcedx, login, authorization

I tried to Authorize an Org with Custom because my Org has custom domain

[image]

- I logged in to PROD with `custom-domain.lightning.force.com` and alias `custom-prod`
- I logged in to UAT with `custom-domain.sandbox.lightning.force.com` and alias `custom-uat`

When I click the switch to switch between different Org. It only displays under Org.

[image]

Question: Is it because I'm using SSO?

Comment: What is PamOrg? Production or Sandbox? you can try running 'sf org list' in your terminal to check the list of connected orgs you have

Comment: Hi @prem22, when I run sf org list. It only shows 1 org which is the recent org I login. For eg, if I log in to UAT first and then I log in to Prod. It will show 1 org as a Prod.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when we have the same username for different orgs. To solve this, we only need to name the username differently.